Upgrade guide .net framework 4.5 to 4.8
We are in the process of upgrading .NET framework version from 4.5 to 4.8 for a legacy application.
We have class library projects, web forms project and an ASP.NET MVC project.

The System.* assemblies for some of the projects in the the .csproj project file look as shown below. I don't think these are installed as nuget packages; instead, I believe these are added as reference from the GAC. Is this assumption correct?
If so, as part of the upgrade process, should I remove these assembly references and install them as nuget packages instead or shall I keep the assemblies as they are?
 <Reference Include="System" />
 <Reference Include="System.Data" />
 <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
 <Reference Include="System.Data.Linq">
     <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
 <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
 <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
 <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
 <Reference Include="System.Web" />
 <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
 <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
 <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
 <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
 <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
 <Reference Include="System.Web.Mobile" />
 <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />


How do I determine should I need to use a newer version of the assemblies than the current ones while upgrading to .NET 4.8?

Here is the collective list of all the System.* assemblies that are referenced in the projects in the solution
 System
 System.Core
 System.Xml.Linq
 System.Data.DataSetExtensions
 System.Data
 System.Xml
 System.Configuration
 System.Data.Linq
 System.Web
 System.Web.ApplicationServices
 System.Web.DynamicData
 System.Web.Entity
 System.Drawing
 System.Web.Extensions
 System.Web.Services
 System.EnterpriseServices
 System.Web.Mobile



